# Jackon deserialization : how to reference another property?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given this example document:

```json
{
    "currency": "USD",
    "items": [{
        "description": "foo",
        "price": 100
    }, {
        "description": "bar",
        "price": 50
    }]
}
```

And these Java classes

```java
class Order {

  Currency currency;

  List<Item> items;

  static class Item {

    String description;

    Money price;

  }

  static class Money {

    BigDecimal amount;

    @SomeDeserializationAnnotation("to reference currency from parent document Order")
    Currency currency

  }

}
```

Does something like `@SomeDeserializationAnnotation("to reference currency from parent document Order")` exist ?

If not, is it even possible with custom deserializer ?

Comment: So your real question is how to get the `"price":100` entry even if it is a separate class in your data structure?

Comment: In fact is is : how to set Money.currency to the same value on Order.currency
I've just found these two annotations that might help but not sure : `JsonBackReference` and `JsonManagedReference`
here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Comment: This wiki only covers the old Jackson 1.x branch. Do you really still use it? I recommend using the 2.x version instead.

Comment: No actually I use 2.x sorry for the old link

Answer (score 1):

First of all @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference will not work here because:
**Annotated property can be a bean, array, Collection (List, Set) or Map type, and it must be a bean property (handled by a property of type serialized using BeanSerializer**

Where currency field is simple String and by default uses 'FromStringDeserializer' (not the BeanDeserializer).

You can solve your problem using custom deserializer for the Order class that will convert the values and use injectable values to convert child objects:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = OrderDeserializer.class)
class Order {
    Currency currency;
    List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    String description;
    Money price;
}

class Money {
    BigDecimal amount;
    Currency currency;

    public Money(BigDecimal amount, @JacksonInject Currency currency) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

}

class OrderDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Order> {

    @Override
    public Order deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectCodec = (ObjectMapper)ctxt.getParser().getCodec();

        JavaType listType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Item.class);

        JsonNode jsonNode = jp.readValueAsTree();
        JsonNode currencyNode = jsonNode.get("currency");
        JsonNode itemsNode = jsonNode.get("items");

        Currency currency = objectCodec.treeToValue(currencyNode, Currency.class);

        InjectableValues values = new InjectableValues.Std().addValue(Currency.class, currency);
        List<Item> items = objectCodec.reader(listType).with(values).readValue(itemsNode);

        return new Order(currency, items);
    }
}
```

The biggest disadvantage here is that you will need to update deserializer implementation if you add/delete/update Order class.